# Performance estimation of shellSort

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, algorithms, definite-integrals, estimation

I'm trying to make a performance estimation for shell-sort algorithm. And I fail in it.

**My formula:**

[image]

equals to

[image]

where dz is outer while-loop, dy is middle for-loop, and dx is inner for-loop (sdee code below)

**Should be:**

[image]

**Question:** what's wrong in my shell sort estimation via integrals?

**Shell Sort implementation (Java):**

```
public static void shellSort(Comparable[] array) {
    int N = array.length;
    int h = 1;
    while (h < N / 3) h = 3 * h + 1;
    while (h >= 1) { //outer loop (dz)
        for (int i = h; i < N; i++) { //middle loop (dy) 
            for (int j = i; j >= h; j -= h) { //inner loop (dx)
                if (array[j].compareTo(array[j - h]) < 0) swap(array, j, j - h);
            }
        }
        h = h / 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Google finds this highly readable [performance analysis](http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/shell/shell.htm) which can be adapted to your question because your gaps are asymptotic to a geometric series and adjacent gaps are coprime to one another. It is in German however, which may or may not work for you.

Comment: If I read you correctly then in order to profit by using insertion sort you should stop swapping in the inner loop as soon as you find a pair of adjacent elements that are in the right order. The code in the English and German Wikipedia entries shifts the entire block up at once and inserts $a[i]$ at the end but the effect should be the same as using swaps. (Actually the block shift is better than swaps by about a factor of two it seems).

Comment: @MarkoRiedel the idea is to estimate via integrals. I've already find the first mistake - the estimation of a while (outer) loop equals integral from 1 to log(3)N instead of N. By log(3)N I mean logarithm from N with 3 basis. But the result is still wrong

Comment: @MarkoRiedel can I do that with help of MatLab?